# A perplexity over the cubic root.

Tags: analysis, exponentiation, radicals, cubics

Good morning; I'm having doubts about a perhaps simple question involving the cubic root of a function. Say I do have the following
$$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{x^3}{2-x^2}}$$

Its domain is clearly $x\neq\pm\sqrt{2}$

Yet I'm having perplexities about the way to write a cubic root. For example, using W. Mathematica to get a plot for the function, I immediately say that there is a huge difference in writing the function with the $\texttt{CubeRoot}$ function, which would define the function I wrote above, and the following way:
$$\left(\dfrac{x^3}{2-x^2}\right)^{1/3}$$

In this case the domain would be $x\in(-\infty, -\sqrt{2}) \cup [0, +\sqrt{2})$, rather different.

So my question is: why and how are there difference between

$$\sqrt[3]{x} ~~~~~~~ \text{and} ~~~~~~~ x^{1/3}$$

Comment: Why does that make the domain different?  For instance, you can still plug $x=-1$ into your second expression, but you say we cannot.  Why?

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{ \frac{x^3}{2-x^2} }=\left( \frac{x^3}{2-x^2}\right)^{1/3}$ in Mathematica and for say $x=3$ they both return the same imaginary root. CubeRoot[x] is different in that in that it returns the real root e.g. for $x=3$.

Comment: @JamesArathoon When I plot the two functions, Mathematica makes different plots. Also FunctionDomain returns different answers...

Comment: Which two functions? You have listed 3 forms in your question although you don't seem to recognise that. Form 1: $\sqrt[3]{x}$ real for $x\ge0$;  Form 2: $x^{1/3}$ real for $x\ge0$; Form 3: CubicRoot[x] real for for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I have already told you that form 3 is different to form 1 and 2 in that it finds the real root for negative $x$.

Comment: In Maple, the same phenomenon happens. If I graph the function with a $1/3$ exponent, the part in the middle $(-\sqrt 2,0)$ is missing whereas if I use surd(function, 3), it reappears.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between $x^{3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$. By definition, $x^{1/n} = \sqrt[n]{x}$. I plotted the two functions on Desmos's graphing calculator (one using a cube root and one using $\frac{1}{3}$ as the exponent) and they showed to be exactly the same. I am not sure why it doesn't work on W. Mathematica.